# Initializing an akka actor using Akka-IO TCP

Tags: scala, akka, akka-io

Using Akka-IO TCP, the procedure to establish connection in an actor is as follow:

```
class MyActor(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {

  IO(Tcp) ! Connect(remote)    //this is the first step, remote is the address to connect to

  def receive = {
    case CommandFailed(_: Connect) => context stop self // failed to connect

    case Connected(remote, local) =>
      val connection = sender()
      connection ! Register(self)
      // do cool things...  
  }
}
```

You send a `Connect` message to `IO(Tcp)` and expect to receive either a `CommandFailed` or a `Connected` message.

Now, my goal is to create an actor that wraps a TCP connection, but I want my actor to start accepting messages only once the connection is established - otherwise, while waiting for the `Connected` message it would start accepting queries but would have no one to send them to.

What I tried:

```
class MyActor(address: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Initialize =>
      IO(Tcp) ! Connect(address)
      context.become(waitForConnection(sender()))

    case other => sender ! Status.Failure(new Exception(s"Connection to $address not established yet."))
  }

  private def waitForConnection(initializer: ActorRef): Receive = {
    case Connected(_, _) =>
      val connection = sender()
      connection ! Register(self)
      initializer ! Status.Success(Unit)
      // do cool things

    case CommandFailed(_: Connect) =>
      initializer ! Status.Failure(new Exception("Failed to connect to " + host))
      context stop self
  }
}
```

My first `receive` is expecting a made-up `Initialize` message that will trigger the whole connection process, once done the sender of `Initialize` receives a success message and knows that it can know start sending queries.

I'm not very happy with it, it forces me to create my actor with

```
val actor = system.actorOf(MyActor.props(remote))
Await.ready(actor ? Initialize, timeout)
```

And it will not be very "restart" friendly.

Any idea to guarantee that my actor won't start receiving messages from the mailbox before the Tcp layer replies with a `Connected`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Stash](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#Stash) trait to stash messages you cannot handle right now. As each premature message arrives, use `stash()` to defer it. Once the connection is open, use `unstashAll()` to return those messages to the mailbox for processing. You can then use `become()` to switch to the message processing state.

Comment: Sounds good. I was thinking about implementing this "buffering" on my own, didn't know there was a built-in trait for that. Thanks, saved me some work :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to make your actor more restart friendly, you can override methods related with actor lifecycle such as `preStart` or `postStop`. [Akka documentation](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html#actor-lifecycle) has good explanation about actor's start, stop and restart hooks.

```
class MyActor(remote: InetSocketAddress) extends Actor {

  override def preStart() {
    IO(Tcp) ! Connect(remote) 
  }

  ...
}
```

Now you can start your actor just with `val actor = system.actorOf(MyActor.props(remote))`. It establish connection on start, and re-establish it on restarts.

Comment: True, but then there is no way to wait for the connection to be fully established before using the actor.

Comment: You can use both this and Bob's solution same time.